# Grails Google map reload markers

Tags: google-maps, grails

I have a google map in a page. When page load, I plot some markers etc. When user change drop downlist i submit xhr via jquery. I have a lot of linkage in my domain class so I hope to use render template & pass in a model. But I have no clue in doing. Or can I render javascript/ Can help? This is how I post.

```
function projectChanged(projectid)
{
      var link = '${createLink(controller:'knowledge', action:'changeSelection')}';
      var type = $("#type1").value;
      var posting = $.post( link , { project: projectid, type:type } );
      posting.done(function( data ) {
       });



}//END project changed
```

Answer (score 0):

in you controller you can do: `render(template:"myTemplate", model: [myData: myData])`